# Largest eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix of a graph

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, adjacency-matrix

Let $G$ be a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. Assume that $\lambda_1$ is the largest eigenvalue of adjacency matrix of $G$. I know that $\lambda_1\geq 2m/n$ with equality holding if and only if $G$ is a regular graph, but I cannot prove it. Could you please help me to prove it?

Comment: Hi mina. The site's guidelines require questions to contain some *context*, meaning some thoughts of your own to show that you've thought about the problem for yourself. Please edit your question with your thoughts on the problem, or the question may be down-voted and closed.

Comment: For example, could you show that if $G$ is a regular graph, then $2m/n$ is an eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix? Also, are you familiar with the [Gershgorin Circle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)?

Comment: You may find some material on graphs looking for Erdös material. I would ask myself what does regular graphs are. I do not really know. :-P

Comment: Also, “I know but cannot prove” sounds like contradicting itself

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix matrix of the graph, $\lambda_1$ its largest eigenvalue. Then $\lambda_1 I - A$ is positive semi-definite. Now
the sum of entries of a positive semi-definite matrix is $\ge 0$. We conclude that 
$$n \lambda_1 - 2 m \ge 0$$

Note that the sum of entries of $\lambda_1 I - A$ equals 
$$\langle (\lambda_1 I - A) v , v\rangle$$
where $v = (1,\ldots, 1)$. If we have equality, $v$ must be in the kernel of $\lambda_1 I - A$.

Comment: I don't understand why your hint is useful. You basically say that $v = (1, \ldots ,1)$ is an eigenvector associated with $\lambda_1$, but how can we conclude that there are no other eigenvectors associated with $\lambda_1$ that are linearly independent with $v$?